# Is Closing Mongo DB Connections for Web App Necessary

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a web app which uses a Mongo Database in the backend. Upon starting the Web Server, a connection to the DB is created using MongoClient.connect. From my front-end app I then make numerous axios.post calls to the DB, some of which return a single row, while others return cursors with several rows. Do I need to close some connections to the database at any point in time, either directly on the backend or from the front-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to close your connection anytime when your backend is running. It is good practice to close the connection when your backend process is shutting down though.

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  mongoclient.close()
});
```